# Verify IAP at start of app

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am in the process of adding an IAP to remove ads from one of my apps.  I have verified that the IAP is working as it should.  My code removes the advertising after the IAP is purchased.  I need to check whether the IAP was purchased when first starting the app, so that I can remove the ads.

I've done a bunch of research on this, and found different methods to do it.  Most of them seem to involve setting up a server that queries the App Store server to determine if an item has been purchased.  I am still trying to figure that out.  I've also seen references to using NSUserDefaults and how that is a bad idea because it's easily hackable by those with jailbroken phones.

My app does not need the device to be online, in order for it to be used.  How can I check to see if an IAP has been purchased, if the device is in airplane mode, or not connected to wifi?  NSUserDefaults would obviously work, but seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: A lot of things are easily hackable by jailbroken phones.

Comment: Generally, putting something in the keychain is seems as a reasonable compromise between server verification and trivial hackability

Comment: NSUserDefaults are even hackeable without jailbroken phones btw.

Comment: They keychain is a great idea.  I just got it all working.  Seems like one downside would be if an IAP was refunded, the user would still get to keep it, as long as it was in the keychain.  Another issue is that the data would survive in the keychain, even when the app was deleted.  Still, it seems to work well.